Не могу развернуть Wheel Collider в Unity
Всем привет! У меня странная проблема, я никак не могу развернуть Wheel Collider в Unity. Хочу сделать движение для колес, посмотрел ролики, но у людей на видео он просто делается нормально и все. У меня же какой-то прикол с этим. Инспектор вообще не помогает, он все время смотрит перпендикулярно колесу!


le déploiement de Wheel Collider dans Unity. C'est un problème commun, surtout pour ceux qui débutent dans le développement de jeux.

Поверни сам автобус или вешай WeelCollider не на колесо, а на какой-нибудь его дочерний объект и вращай уже его (или колесо, смотря что будет шевелиться).
